# Can AJAX server side processing run concurrently?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I understand that JavaScript is single threaded.  If you have an AJAX call then it is added to the message queue and JavaScript deals with it when it can.  Say I have a function like this:

```
function TestAjax
{
   //AJAX asynchronous call 1
   //AJAX asynchronous call 2
   //AJAX asynchronous call 3
}
```

Say the code above adds three HTML tables to a webpage (one table added per function), then I take it that AJAX asynchronous call 3 could produce the first table even though it was added to the message queue last.

I am trying to understand if the three calls could run at the same time as they are AJAX calls were the content is generated on the server.

Comment: Sure, why wouldn't they?

Comment: @Bergi, I am relatively new to asynchronous code, message queues and JavaScript.  Is there a separate thread for the message queue?

Comment: Think about this: 3 million people are trying to access your site, you have Apache + PHP (or whatever, it doesnt really matter). Would all this queries be answered concurrently? Why wouldn't AJAX calls then?

Comment: There's a separate "thread" for each HTTP request, but there's only one message queue that processes JavaScript callbacks.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks.  What thread makes the call to the server side?

Comment: Each HTTP "thread" makes one <s>call</s> request.

Comment: @Bergi, I see.  The call to the server side is immediate i.e. AJAX asynchronous call 1 is always sent to the server first.  It is the callback that is added to the event queue.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the first call is sent first. No, the callback is added to the event queue when the response has arrived - that's why their order is unknown, and depends on network & server timing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can run at the same time and you could experience "staggered" results (like the 2nd one finishing before the first).  It all depends on how much processing is required on the server side.  If your second call is to a function that returns an empty string, but your first call queries a large database, you can expect the empty string to get returned before your DB results.

Why, specifically, are you concerned with the order in which they complete?

Comment: Thanks, I am not concerned about it.  I am just trying to understand the process.  +1.

Comment: @w0051977 Please remember to upvote any answers that helped you and accept the answer that best answers your question.  This helps future users with similar problems more easily find the best solution.

Comment: I was one of the two up voters for this question.  I understand this subject better these days and I believe your answer is well written.  Therefore I will now mark the question as answered.  Thanks for the reminder.